# Volume generated by shell method of y = 4

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, volume, solid-of-revolution

$$\mathrm{x = 4y-y^2, x = 0, y = 4…}$$ Volume by shell method.

I am just confused with everything. I cannot figure out, the radius, and height. Any help would be appreciated thanks.
The radius I took was (4-y) and the function (right - left) which came $\mathrm{(4y-y^2)}$

$$\mathrm{A = 2 \pi \int [4-y] \left[4y-y^2\right] dy}$$

So, I am unsure if I should subtract $$\mathrm{4y - y^2 \ or \ y^2 - 4y}.$$ There is no clear top or bottom/ left or right function and only one point of intersection. Thanks.

Comment: First sketch the parabola to be rotated on y-axis

Comment: This will give you an advantage: [Question Guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour), and [MathJax Guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Enjoy! Simply stating that “I do not know” will not cut it, at least try something, anything. Also, this looks like Calc. 2 homework. What is the context for this, and all problems, problem?

Comment: It is rotating on y axis or x axis, because horizentally y = 4. The other problem with this question is that there is only one point of intersection, so I do not know what should be the limit of integration.

Comment: @smith I made the same error before in my self answer. If you are rotating around the axis x,y=0 then it should be y not 4-y even though those are the same y axes. I think your are rotating around y=4,0 as these give the same surface and therefore revolution.

Answer (score 1):

First here is the graph:

[image]

[Here](https://www.math3d.org/4RADRX6p) is a graph of this rotated about y=0 or y=4 shifted down.

The range for y, the integration variable is $0\le y\le 4$:
$$\mathrm{A=2\pi\int_0^4(4-y)(4y-y^2)dy=2\pi\int_0^4y(4y-y^2)dy=2\pi\int_0^4 4y^2-y^3dy=2\pi\bigg[\frac{4y^3}{3}-\frac{y^4}{4}\bigg]_0^4=\frac{128}3\pi\ (units)=134.04128655...}$$

Try switching the $4y-y^2$ and you will see that this just makes the answer negative. Try also with the (4-y) term and you will see this has the same value. Please correct me and provide me feedback!